# Unable to read most recently added to SQL Server Compact Edition

Tags: c#

I'm trying to implement a function to view the most recently added item to a SQL Server CE database:

```
private void BackButt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
       SqlCeDataReader myReader = null;

       SqlCwCommand cm = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT MAX(TS_Process) AS Expr1, MAX(TS_Verify) AS Expr2 FROM TestStep", cn)

       myReader = cm.ExecuteReader();

       while (myReader.Read())
       {
           stepTB.Text = myReader.GetString(0);
           ExpectedTB.Text = myReader.GetString(1);
       }
    }      
    catch (SqlCeException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

Connection is opened at form load.

This only displays the last entry and does not display all previous entries.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: first you say you want to view the most recently added item, then you say you only get back the last entry and that you want to see all previous entries aswell...what exactly do you want?

Comment: currently only the last entry(Most recent) is returned but entries previous to the last entry in the DB are not displayed. I want to be able to step back to the first entry in the DB.

Comment: so you ONLY want to display the FIRST (oldest) entry ?

Comment: No, I want to be able to view all the entries from last to first viewing each step when selecting the back button. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quick and easy fix, below code will do what you asked, altho this is not the way you're gonna want to use it.

```
        while (myReader.Read())
         {
          stepTB.Text += myReader.GetString(0) + " ";

          ExpectedTB.Text += myReader.GetString(1) + " ";
         }
```

if you want an actual overview, look up datacontrols such as [repeaters](http://www.netrostar.com/Tutorials-91-ASP.NET%20Tutorial.%20How%20to%20use%20Repeater) and [gridviews](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.be/2008/10/gridview-example-how-to-use-gridview-in.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help. this returns every entry at the same time though  . thanks again